# DBLinq or MySQL .NET Conector for large game servers in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Im working on a server that will have a lot of users connected at the same time and I need to connect to a SQL Database. Searching I found that there are two ways of using a MySQL database under C#, using MySql .NET Connector and DBLinq. I want to ask which is the best method for large servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget DBLinq, it's dead.  And when I spent time on it about two years ago it had many many edge case bugs.

BTW, DBLinq is an ORM wrapper that uses a MySql driver, which is probably the MySql .NET Connecter you've already found.